# iOS6 UIImage causes crash

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, ios6

Since iOS6 I have a very weird issue with UIImages that causes the application to crash.
The full method is like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json"];

NSDictionary *parametros = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                            URL:url
                            parameters:parametros];
[request setAccount:account];
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSError *error_ = nil;
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error_];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [_imageCache setObject:image forKey:account.username];
                [ListAccount reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:NO];
            });
        }
    }];
```

The problem occur in this line

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
```

This was no problem in iOS5. I can't seem to find why or someone that had the same problem. Any suggestion will be really appreciated

The crash is the following:

```
2012-09-28 17:30:53.600 Catalogo[7321:c07] -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector     sent to instance 0x10eaf180
2012-09-28 17:30:53.601 Catalogo[7321:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to     instance 0x10eaf180'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2aed012 0x1a28e7e 0x2b784bd 0x2adcbbc 0x2adc94e 0x2a75390 0x203630c 0x2035e7e 0x2035d98     0x10dc23d 0xf991f3 0xf98ef4 0x6c54e 0x1b9e731 0x1bad014 0x1b9d7d5 0x2a93af5 0x2a92f44     0x2a92e1b 0x2dd87e3 0x2dd8668 0xf7765c 0x79cd 0x2d45)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The following:

```
[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]
```

return the url of a twitter profile image

Comment: Could you NSLog userInfo and give information about the error?

Comment: I've edited the post according to your requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert **`[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]`** into `NSData`, then pass it to **imageWithData:**.

```
NSString * profileImageString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
NSData * profileImageData = [profileImageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Than use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:profileImageData];
```

Comment: tried:
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
still no luck, this error was thrown:
-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2218e0

Comment: Convert the NSString to NSURL **[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]]];**

Comment: tried your last edit but still no luck:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: enf_4eva)'